# ContentScaleFactor on UIKit elements broken?

Tags: iphone, uiview, scrollview, blurry

I'm trying to make sure my UILabel's and UITextView's stay sharp when they exist within a UIScrollView. I came along the 'contentScaleFactor' property on the UIView class, it seems to work perfectly fine on custom drawing but UITextView's and Labels just refuse to redraw themselves at the right contentscale.

http://pastebin.com/PBjhjMbR

Maybe this is due that the actual views that draw the text are a subview of these classes?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set contentScaleFactor recursively on all subviews and also call setNeedsDisplay on each view that you set it on to make them display at higher quality. I have also found that it is not worth setting it on a UIImageView because they won't render at higher quality anyway so there's no point in wasting memory by making their backing layers bigger.

Comment: which is not an way apple would allow, besides it's not that easy to find the actual text layer somewhere down in the textview. I asked at WWDC they told me to file a bug report, they didn't have a clue either.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but the method I gave above is exactly what I was told to do at WWDC by an Apple engineer. The app I used it in is already in the app store so Apple does in fact allow it (why wouldn't they? it's a public API).The only problem I've had with it is that it doesn't work on text fields while they are being edited (i.e., while the keyboard is up). For some reason in that case something is setting the contentScaleFactor of the relevant view back to the default, and I couldn't figure out how to set it late enough to make that work properly.

Comment: That's the whole point of my problem however, non-edited state I'm just showing my own view with the right contentscale. The editing state is the problem.