# UITextView and contentScaleFactor

Tags: zooming, uitextview

I have a number of text contols in a scrollView that can be zoomed. In order to redraw the controls at a higher resolution to avoid blurry text, I set each view's contentScaleFactor in the view hierarchy as explained **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975276/contentscalefactor-on-uikit-elements-broken?answertab=votes#tab-top).** Everything works fine for labels and textfields but textViews do not redraw at the higher scale factor. I noticed that the only other subview for textViews that may make a difference if set is a private class UIWebDocumentView which implements content like UIWebView ( ie WebKit) but the new scale factor is ignored if set at either level ( UITextView or UIWebDocumentView ).

Any ideas how to reset the scale factor ( resolution ) for TextViews specifically ?

Answer (score 4):

Setting the `contentScaleFactor` and `contentsScale` is in fact the key, as @dbotha pointed out, however you have to walk the view and layer hierarchies separately in order to reach every internal `CATiledLayer` that actually does the text rendering. You also need to account for the screen scale.

The implementation would be something like this:

```objc
- (void)updateForZoomScale:(CGFloat)zoomScale {
    CGFloat screenAndZoomScale = zoomScale * [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    // Walk the layer and view hierarchies separately. We need to reach all tiled layers.
    [self applyScale:(zoomScale * [UIScreen mainScreen].scale) toView:self.textView];
    [self applyScale:(zoomScale * [UIScreen mainScreen].scale) toLayer:self.textView.layer];
}

- (void)applyScale:(CGFloat)scale toView:(UIView *)view {
    view.contentScaleFactor = scale;
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        [self applyScale:scale toView:subview];
    }
}

- (void)applyScale:(CGFloat)scale toLayer:(CALayer *)layer {
    layer.contentsScale = scale;
    for (CALayer *sublayer in layer.sublayers) {
        [self applyScale:scale toLayer:sublayer];
    }
}
```

You can than call this when the zoom scale changes (part of `UIScrollViewDelegate`):

```objc
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale {
    [self updateForZoomScale:scale];
}
```

I filed an enhancement request here: rdar://21443666 (http://www.openradar.me/21443666). There's also a sample project with the workaround attached.

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to apply the contentScaleFactor to all subviews of the UITextView. I've just tested the following with a UITextView and found it to work:

```
- (void)applyScale:(CGFloat)scale toView:(UIView *)view {
    view.contentScaleFactor = scale;
    view.layer.contentsScale = scale;
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        [self applyScale:scale toView:subview];
    }
}
```

Comment: For me, this works when first creating the text view, but not later when updating after a zoom has been performed. To work around the issue I remove the old text view from the view hierarchy and replace it wit an exact copy with the appropriate `contentScaleFactor` applied.