# How to zoom text in UitextView using stepper in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, xib, uistepper

i have a UiTextView and UiStepper in Xib and i want to zoom the content of textView by using stepper in objective c.thanks

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159776/uitextview-and-contentscalefactor

Comment: i am trying to scale the textView size using stepper when i clicked + icon for zoom in and - icon for zoom out in objective c @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 1):

For scale(zoom) text

```
- (void)scaleTextView:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchGestRecognizer{
     CGFloat scale = pinchGestRecognizer.scale;

    createTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:createTextView.font.fontName size:createTextView.font.pointSize*scale];

    [self textViewDidChange:createTextView];       
}
```

It scales the font size and then recalculates the content size using your code in `textViewDidChange`.

Comment: i just mention stepper only. @Vivek Gajbe

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
[stepper addTarget:self action:@selector(stepperValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
stepper.tag = indexPath.row;
stepper.stepValue = 1;
stepper.continuous = YES;
stepper.minimumValue = 0;
stepper.maximumValue = 10;
```

**Selector**

```
- (IBAction)stepperValueChanged:(UIStepper *)sender 
{
  NSUInteger value = sender.value;
    txtView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:value];
}
```